# How to restore performance of hadoop Map reduce job after migrating from hadoop1 to hadoop2

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, amazon-emr

Hadoop Map reduce job performance(time to execute job) degraded(5min->15min) after migrating from hadoop 1.0.3 -> hadoop 2.8.5

Details below:

I have Hadoop Map reduce job executing in AWS EMR environment.

**Hadoop 1.0.3 Environment details:**
AMI Version: 2.4.11
Hadoop Version: 1.0.3

Step 1(only 1 step) of EMR job takes **5 minutes** to run with testing instance consisting of 1 master and 1 core(aws terminology). In hadoop dashboard I have my application consisting of a single job.

- Nuber of Mapper tasks in job:524
- Number of reducer tasks in job:7
- Machine configs(R3.2xlarge: 8VCPU, 61Gib RAM, 160GB SSD)

**Hadoop 2.8.5 Environment details:**

In Hadoop 2.8.5 environment, the same mapreduce job takes **~15 minutes** to run with all the same configs (1master, 1 core)

- Number of Mapper tasks in job:524
- Number of reducer tasks in job:{3,7} // Tried with both 3 and 7 reducers
- Machine configs(R5.2xlarge: 8VCPU, 64Gib RAM, 350GB EBS)

Config values

- yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb =32
- yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb = 57344

  - Other info about the job run with Hadoop 2.8.5 MR job
  - Elapsed:   15mins, 5sec
  - Diagnostics:
  - Average Map Time   7sec
  - Average Shuffle Time   10mins, 51sec
  - Average Merge Time 0sec
  - Average Reduce Time    0sec

What I have tried:
Tweaked around following settings but performance in terms of **time to execute the job is not changing in any scenario.** Sharing values of one of the scenarios tested

- mapreduce.map.java.opts = -Xmx5734m
- mapreduce.reduce.java.opts = Xmx11468m

Below I am mentioning different combinations tried

- mapreduce.map.memory.mb   = {4163, 9163 , 7163}
- mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb = {2584, 6584 , 3584}

Since there is a resource manager architectural change in hadoop2, I experimented around it but is there anything I may be missing. My Proficiency level in Hadoop: Beginner

Answer (score 0):

The issue was **the small file problem** in Hadoop map-reduce. In Hadoop V1.0.3, this problem was being over-shadowed by resuing the JVM containers(mapred.job.reuse.jvm.num.tasks).

However, in Hadoop V2, reusing the JVM container is not allowed. Using Uber mode is also not viable as it will run all the map tasks in the ApplicationMaster container sequentially.

Using `CombineTextInputFormat.setMaxInputSplitSize(job, bytes)` solved the small file problem as it created a logical split based on the number of bytes provided as an argument.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CombineFileInputFormat.html